# Volume of sphere inside a cylinder

Tags: integration, volume

I have homework question:

Calculate the volume of $\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2\le (2a)^2\} \cap \{(x,y,z) \mid (x-a)^2 + y^2 \le a^2\}$

in two ways:

1) Polar coordinates

2) Spherical coordinates

How can I solve it?

Edit: What I tried:

$$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a r\sqrt{4a^2-x^2-y^2}\,dr\,d\theta = 2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a r\sqrt{4a^2-(a+r\cos\theta)^2-r\sin^2\theta}\,dr\,d\theta \\
= 2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a r\sqrt{3a^2-2ar\cdot\cos\theta - r^2}\,dr\,d\theta = \: ?$$

Edit: I need answer with one of the two ways.

Answer (score 2):

For cylindrical coordinates:
$$z=\pm \sqrt{4a^2-(x^2+y^2)}$$
Using polar coordinates

$$x=r\cos\phi  \ , \ y=r\sin \phi $$
we end up with
$$z=\pm \sqrt{4a^2-r^2}$$
now, just integrate
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2a\cos \phi}\int_{-\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}rdzdrd\phi=2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2a\cos \phi}r\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}dzdrd\phi$$

For spherical coordinates:
$$ x=r\cos\phi \sin \theta \ , \ y = r\sin \phi \sin \theta \ , \ z = r\cos \theta \ , \ J=r^2\sin \theta $$

Comment: The $r$ limit should be $2a\cos\phi$. Spherical coordinates is rather unnatural for this problem. You need two separate integrals and the limits are not commonplace.